# What are these UI elements for viewing videos called?

Tags: terminology

YouTube has this nice functionality, where if you hover over the controls, you can see a preview frame of the time you're hovering above:

[image]

Is there a specific name for this kind of preview?

Also, somewhat related: Elgato's Game Capture HD software displays the controls of the video like this:
[image]

Where the controls over the video's time are displayed using different frames from the video. Is there a name for this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how official this is, but the term "scrubber" or "scrub bar" will come up quite often.

If you specifically mean the preview pane with the thumbnail, then perhaps "scrubber preview" or "seek preview" are what you are looking for.

I won't bias my answer with links, but if you Google any of the above terms you should get plenty of references to make your own mind up.

Note that this term isn't limited to just video though. It can be used for audio and even photo galleries. So depending on the context you use it in, you might need to explicit say "video scrubber preview", for example.

Answer (score 0):

In general terms you can call them "Scrubbing Preview", "Thumbnails Preview" or more specifically "Video Scrubbing Preview".